# Show modal when using javascript confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function that will show a modal:

```
confirmModal: function (message) {

// CODE TO SHOW MODAL HAS BEEN REMOVED FOR THIS QUESTION //

}
```

And because it's been namespaced it's called like: `uiModal.confirmModal('Test message');`

Inside the modal I have two buttons:

```
<button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
<button class="ok">Ok</button>
```

Now what I want to do is two things:

1. When I do something like: `onsubmit="confirm('Are you sure?');"` or `onclick="confirm('Are you sure?');"` it will show the modal instead of an alert box. Note that it needs to work for both links and form submits.
2. The two buttons in the modal need to either cancel or allow the request to happen. I have already got the cancel to close the modal fine so it's just a case of allowing or denying the request to happen.

Can anyone help? I've looked at some other questions on here and seen bits about using `window.location($(this).attr('href'))` but that would only work on links and not for the submit of a form.

I've also looked at doing window.confirm = uiModal.confirmModal('message'); but how would I use that in my example of an onclick or onsubmit

Thanks

Comment: not sure I really understood the question but have you thought about just binding the submit button to this action? and then waiting for input from the user to cancel the default submit event or letting it bubble?

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt work because `confirm` is a blocking call (the javascript won't continue when the box is open), while your modal dialog isn't.

You can solve it by doing something like:

```
// have some temp var that holds confirmation state
var isConfirmed = false;
$("form").submit(function () {
    // when someone tries to submit the form, verify whether it's confirmed
    if (!isConfirmed) {
        // show modal dialog

        // prevent direct submit
        return false;
    }
});

// when hitting the OK button in the modal, change the confirmation state
$(".modal .ok").click(function () {
    isConfirmed = true;
    // and re-submit the form
    $("form").submit();
});
```